# Communication between C and C# program on RPI3

Tags: c, software-development, communication, c#, software-compatibility

I have a question i wondered by myself if it is possible to communicate between a C# and C programm.

I want to use the C# program for the user interface and then send commands to the C program that has to excute some things like control an output or take a picture with a camera or...

So is it possible and have you some links or examples that can help me?

I know that i can made a server in the C programm that receive tcp packets from the cliënt (C# program) that runs all on the localhost but i want it without the server stuff :p .

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid writing the server part in my opinion. The most simple way would be to use an existing buffer or queue system through TCP like RabbitMQ or Mosquitto.

I have a personal project having the same requirements as  yours (different languages) and what I've finally done is to setup a RabbitMQ server to deliver the messages. Besides, I can now disengage both programs and execute them wherever or in the same machine. Of course you will have to define the content of the messages (I use normally JSON, but you can send any plain text).

Have a look at:

1. https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c and https://www.rabbitmq.com/.
2. https://mosquitto.org/

Hope it helps